# Nginx serve static files for flask app 404

Tags: nginx, python, fedora, static-content, flask

I've tried numerous solutions of other posts, but nothing seems to work for me, I always get a `404` error, when trying to let `nginx` serve static files of my `flask` application. Somewhere in between all those attempts on getting it to run, I also had a `403`, but I can't reconstruct it. This is my current setup:

The app is in: `~/development/Python/flask_nginx_gunicorn/`, which is supposed to be a test project for getting everything running, understanding nginx and so on. It has the following structure:

[image: project structure]

So there is nothing more than a file called `app.py`, which configures a few routes and an `index.html` in the `static` folder.

I configured my `nginx` as follows:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with the following content:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

At the end there is an include for the `sites-enabled` sub directory. In that directory I have a file called `flask_project`. In that file I have the following configuration for my project:

```
server {

    root /home/xiaolong/development/Python/flask_nginx_gunicorn/;

    server_name localhost;

    # LISTENING ON WHICH PORTS?
    listen localhost:7777;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /home/xiaolong/development/Python/flask_nginx_gunicorn/;
    }
}
```

I started `nginx` using the command `systemctl start nginx`. When it is running, and I do a `ps -aux | grep nginx`, I get the following output:

```
root     17748  1.2  2.5 1607328 102772 pts/1  Sl   20:45   0:07 /usr/local/sublime_text_3/sublime_text /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
root     18762  0.0  0.0 122720  2880 ?        Ss   20:53   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx    18763  0.0  0.1 124808  7916 ?        S    20:53   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    18764  0.0  0.1 124808  7916 ?        S    20:53   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    18765  0.0  0.1 124808  7916 ?        S    20:53   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    18766  0.0  0.1 124808  7916 ?        S    20:53   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     18988  0.0  0.0 111032  1792 pts/0    S+   20:54   0:00 tail -f 10 /var/log/nginx/error.log
root     19001  0.0  0.0 115820  2396 pts/1    S+   20:55   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

So I know it is running. I used to get an error in the log, telling me `nginx` couldn't bind to a specific port, which was caused by `SELinux` only allowing certain ports for it to bind to. I fixed that using the command `semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 7777`.

After each change I always ran `systemctl restart nginx`, to restart the `nginx` server, so that it can reload its configuration.

I use `gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8080` to run my flask app.

When I open the URL `http://localhost:8080/static/` in the browser, I get a `404` and the log I read using `tail -f 10 /var/log/nginx/error.log` states no new errors. The flask app is running though, which I can verify by going to: `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/data`, which both work fine. However, once there is static content from the static directory, I get the `404`.

My guesses are the following:

1. Somehow `nginx` is not being talked to and it doesn't know about the request for the static folder content.
2. Somehow the paths are still not correct.
3. There is some other issue that prevents it from getting the file for the browser and making it not log that.

I've tried to get it running for two days now, but none of the configurations I found worked for me. I also tried the following two commands, which were suggested in other places:

1. Change Security Context of a Directory recursively:

   `chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /home/xiaolong/development/Python/flask_nginx_gunicorn/`
2. Allow the http daemon to connect using the network (???)

   `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

What's wrong with my configuration?

**Additional Info**

In my `/etc/nginx/` directory I have the following structure:

- one `nginx.conf` file
- sub directory `sites-available` containing only the config for my flask app
- sub directory `sites-enabled` containing a link to my config file for the flask app in `sites-available`

I am running a `Fedora 22` here.

Comment: Would using an `alias` instead of `root` help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias

Comment: @mattingly890 Nah, didn't change anything. Not even a message in that log file.

Answer (score 2):

This is over a year old at this point so I'm sure you've worked this out, but in case anyone else sees this:

Nginx is listening on `localhost:7777`, but your URL is taking you to port 8080 where your gunicorn server lives. This is why you can get to your Flask app (served by gunicorn) but not your static content (served by ngninx). This is also why you're not getting anything in your nginx logs. If you go to `http://localhost:7777/`, nginx should pass your request through to your Flask app, and `http://localhost:7777/static/` should take you to the static content.

Comment: I never figured it out back then and the project died. I also won't build it up again, but thanks for the explanation. Good for others and maybe when I need to do sth. like this again for me too. Also I can put away that impression that it simply did not work on Fedora or mysyeriously did not work, as there now seems to be an explanation.